# Can a pre-compiled Function App have multiple functions in it?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Can a pre-compiled Function App have multiple functions in it?

Reading the [docs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) it details use of the functions.json to point at the entrypoint in the dll.

But can you have multiple entrypoints in a single functions.json, ans so expose multiple methods in a single DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function App can have multiple functions, each one of them in a separate folder and with separate `function.json` file referencing to the proper entry point.

So the folder structure should be like this:

```
bin\MyCompiledAssembly.dll
NameOfYourFunction\function.json
AnotherFunction\function.json
appsettings.json
host.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You really have two questions here, with different answers:

> Can a pre-compiled Function App have multiple functions in it?

Yes, both the Function App **as well as** the assembly may have multiple functions. You can define the functions in your Function App as you normally would, with the folder structure where each function has its own folder with its `function.json` file **and** you can expose multiple function methods from your assembly, and make sure those are properly set in the `entryPoint` property of your `function.json` files.

> But can you have multiple entrypoints in a single functions.json

No. Each function has a single entry point. But different methods in the same assembly may be referenced by different functions.